What to do when you have a 7 by 7 matrix?

We need to find the coefficient of $x^5$ in the expression of the determinant
$$\left| {\begin{matrix}1 & x & 5 & 1 & 7 & 10 & 6\\x & 5 & 1 & 10 & 2 & 7 & x\\5 & 1 & 5 & 4 & 6 & x & 9\\1 & 10 & 4 & 8 & x & 5 & 5\\7 & 2 & 6 & x & 4 & 8 & 5\\10 & 7 & x & 5 & 8 & 1 & 2\\6 & x & 9 & 5 & 5 & 2 & 5\end{matrix}} \right|$$

At first glance it may seem that the numbers are not chosen randomly and there is some symmetry. But no, it is not so! I could not find anything adequate. First I tried to find the derivative
$$\frac{d^5}{dx^5} \det(A(x)) = \frac{d^5}{dx^5} \left[ \sum_{\sigma \in S_6} \text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^6 A_{i, \sigma(i)}(x) \right]$$
But I don't want to calculate about 21 large matrices, from which more than 100 matrices appear. Although this method is not so complicated, if we calculated through minors
Yes, calculating through minors will take a long time and be inefficient. I tried to find a pattern in Pascal's triangle, but there is no triple, which is very annoying
There was another idea: try to rearrange the columns so that the x's are on the diagonal, and one $x$ is in the corner, but nothing worked either
Zeroing the rows or columns also does not help, since there will be no fewer calculations and this is very long
I don't quite understand. If there is such an assignment with a 7 by 7 matrix, then the teacher does not mean to calculate the determinant directly, right? I don't know any theorems or lemmas to find the coefficient, rather than calculating the determinant of 7 by 7
Can someone show me some pattern that I haven't seen or some efficient way to calculate the determinant?

It might be easier to use the permutation definition of the the determinant to implement Calvin's proof strategy. Then you need to look at all ways of choosing 5 x's out of the 8, and then looking at what the other factors could be in that summand of the determinant.

Try using elementary row operations to cancel some of the $x$'s. For example $(-1)R_1+R_7\to R_7$. This does not affect the determinant. You can do a similar column operation after that.

Combining the previous two comments seems to work well. You can use row/column operations to leave you with the determinant of a matrix with six $x$'s, from which the permutation calculation is easier.

Hint: With this setup, it's quite hard to choose 7 terms in distinct rows and columns, such that we choose exactly 5 $x's$.
Are there any particular $x$'s that we seem to have to use? Hence, what row/column should we do the cofactor expansion on?
As an example,  since we cannot find 7 terms in distinct rows and columns, such that we choose exactly 7 $x's$, hence the determinant has no $x^7$ term.
As another example, for $ \begin{pmatrix}  a & x & b  \\ x & c & x \\ d & x & e  \end{pmatrix}$, since there is no way to choose exactly 1 $x$ out of 3 terms in distinct rows and columns, hence we can conclude that there is no linear $x$ term in the discriminant without having to expand it out.

Hint for another solution: Notice that if we not use an $x$ in  the "second row or the second column", then there is at most a $x^4$ term. Hence, we must use the second row or the second column in the cofactor expansion, and can limit to the 2 with an $x$.
As an example, using the matrix in the second example, if we did a cofactor expansion along the 2nd row, then we see that each term is either 1 or $x^2$, so there is no linear nor $x^3$ term.

Yes, you need to determine the coefficient before $x^5$

I agree that the determinant does not have $x^7$, but how will this help in finding the coefficient $x^5$?

@Dmitry It is given as an example of how to use the idea. IE If there is no way to find 7 $x$'s, then there is no $x^7$ term. $\quad$ If there is only 1 way (not saying this is true) to find 5 $s'$s, then we can easily calculate the coefficient as the product of the other 2 terms, along with the appropriate sign.
